# Give a warning to users on retagging sprees

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

The edit review queue on Stack Overflow (and possibly other sites) is regularly filled up by users on retagging sprees.

Retagging is not necessarily bad, but retagging sprees are a bit of a problem.
Sometimes, it's a user trying to gain lots of rep the cheap way. Other times, it's users who genuinely believe they are doing the right thing... only to be called out on Meta, and finding out that people have denounced their actions behind their backs.
Meanwhile, the reviewers burn through review slots that are also needed to judge more involved edits.
Also, retagging bumps questions to the front page, flooding it and drowning out newer questions.

My suggestion is that if a user suggests several edits (say 3 edits within 5 minutes) that consist only of the same retag, a warning is given. Not unlike the warning users get after an edit has been rejected.

The warning could, for example, read:

> You've been making edits that consist only of changing tags. Before you continue, make sure that there is consensus on [link to per-site meta] that these retags are needed.

Comment: If they're *only* editing the tag then why not just block them, you *know* they're not being helpful at that point.

Comment: @Servy Let's give them a warning first. If the retagging is deemed bad and the editor won't listen, then mods can impose an edit suspension.

Comment: You did notice that the SOCVR room leave a precautionary comment on meta posts that probably set these sprees into motion? Example [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321229/burninate-planning-is-not-for-projects/321249#comment334198_321229)

Comment: @rene I've seen Tunaki's comment a number of times. But it advises _against_ retagging sprees.

Comment: Yes, that comment was made a bit stronger when we got feedback on MSO.

Comment: Problem of the site, not of the user.

Comment: @pfnuesel Which is why I'm suggesting a change to the site. Even mass retags are _sometimes_ useful. But the editor should have meta consensus first.